# How to restore ability to see server-stored mail drafts under "All Drafts" section of Favorites in MacOS Mail.app

Tags: mail.app, big-sur

I have several IMAP email accounts whose drafts are stored on their respective servers, and I have gathered these draft folders into the "All Drafts" section of Favorites in MacOS Big Sur Mail.app.

In the last few weeks, I can no longer see these drafts by selecting "All Drafts" as I used to. The level of "All Drafts" shows the badge for the total number of drafts inside it across all accounts, but the message window is blank when "All Drafts" is selected. Instead, I now have to click the triangle and go down to the level of the specific account's draft folder itself to see or access any of my drafts.

What has changed? How do I go back to previous situation of being able to access any server-stored draft from any account under the "All Drafts" favorite folder? Can I reset this behavior without losing all my email accounts and settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I had mistakenly turned on a filter for the "All Drafts" favorite folder and didn't realize it. Disabling the filter solved the problem. Sorry!

Comment: Consider marking your answer as accepted if it answers your problem as you said. It avoids it being bumped by Community bot as unsolved.

Comment: Done -- thanks!

Comment: :)ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ